# ISO C90/99 Check if compiler specific function exists

Tags: c

So I'm writing portable embedded ansi C code that is attempting to support multiple compilers and hardware targets.  Each compiler/hardware vendor has different math.h functions it supports.  Some support only C90, some support a subset of C99, others a full set of C99.

I'm trying to find a way to check if a given function exists during preprocessor so that I can use a custom macro if it doesn't exist.  Some vendors have extern functions in the math.h, some use #define to remap to some internal call.  Is there a piece of code that can tell if it is #defined or an extern function? I can use #ifdef for the define, but what about an actual function call?

Comment: Does checking if the compiler support C99 satisfy you?

Comment: You need [`autoconf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).  Yes, it is kind of a pain in the butt to work with, but it is the best tool that exists for this specific job.  (It implements for you the process of "writing a series of test .c files, compiling them, looking at the error codes coming back, and setting appropriate -D flags" suggested by keshlam.)

Comment: You can also use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) which is a better alternative to `autoconf` because it's portable.  Also it's quite easy to use

Comment: @user9000: CMake is not a better alternative. It's not portable, and it has lots of ugly hard-coded assumptions and hacks rather than correct checks. This doesn't make autoconf *good*, and in fact autoconf scripts often do their checks wrong too, but at least with autoconf it's *possible* to get the checks right. See my blog post at http://ewontfix.com/13/

Comment: @YuHao Nope, some compilers claim C99 support, but don't have all the libraries, they just support C99 coding syntax.

Comment: @Zack ok, thanks, I guess its that or manually specifying defines for each environment to set up the proper routines

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is instead to look at macros defined by the preprocessor itself, or passed into the build process as `-D` definitions, which identify the compiler and platform you're running on, and use those plus your knowledge of what special assists each environment needs to configure your code.

I suppose you could write a series of test .c files, try compiling them, look at the error codes coming back, and use those to set appropriate `-D` flags... but I'm not convinced that would be any cleaner.

Comment: If OP ends up writing a check script rather than using an existing autoconf recipe or similar, please take into account the issues I covered here: http://ewontfix.com/13/